# Using firestore with google heatmap

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, heatmap

Please, I want to pass data (latitude and longitude) retrieved from firestore to another function with javascript,

I have retrieved the data but I want to pass it to getpoint() function, how can I do that with firestore?

Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
// get data from database

 var db = firebase.firestore();

  const list_div = document.querySelector("#list_div");

 // get data 
   var positions = [];


    var loca = db.collection("locations").get().then((snapshot) =>{
        snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {

        var positions_list = 
    [doc.data().position.geopoint.latitude,doc.data().position.geopoint.longitude];
        //console.log(positions_list);
        //var test = snapshot.val().name;
        //var hhh = [doc.data().position.geopoint.longitude];
        positions  = positions.concat(positions_list); 
        //console.log(test);

      // list_div.innerHTML += "<li class='list_item' >"+ doc.data().position.geopoint.latitude + ", " + doc.data().position.geopoint.longitude +"</li>"
});
return positions;
});

  // Google maps

    var map, heatmap;

   function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 13,
      center: {lat: 35.302810, lng: -1.182780},
      mapTypeId: 'satellite'
    });

    heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
      data: getPoints(),
      map: map
    });
  }

  // Heatmap data: 500 Points
  function getPoints() {
    return [
      new google.maps.LatLng(35.302810, -1.182780),

      ];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use a map of your docs results and call inside this map your method getPoint(lat,long) with the correct parameters to retrieve directly have your points while retrieving your data from Firestore ?

Comment: can you explain more please ?

Comment: db.collection("locations").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
      querySnapshot.map((doc) => {
        this.getPoints(doc.data().position.geopoint.latitude, doc.data().position.geopoint.longitude);
      });
    });

Comment: i got this error : Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: querySnapshot.map is not a function

Comment: i got this : Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'NaN' of undefined
    at visualization_impl.js:2